# Load forecast model with temperature data

Tags: regression, forecasting

I would like to estimate a regression model of the type:

$
load_t  = seasonality_t + trend_t + \beta * temperature_t,
$

and I have load data and temperature on high frequency (hourly data). My impression is that
the temperature does not influence load at the same frequency as I measure load (i.e. a change in temperature for 2 or 3 hours does not imply a change in load immediately). This is how I understand the application of the concept of coherency as in http://eprints.nuim.ie/1968/1/JR_C81dfisf.pdf

I tried to look at average temperature per day and use this in the regression but the results were not satisfying. How can we incorporate temperature into a practical model in the best way? Any hints? Good references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use lagged temperatures with spline functions (not linear). There is a big literature on this. See, for example, http://robjhyndman.com/papers/stlf/

Comment: I am not familiar with the concept of regression splines - do you have any good reference at hand? Thank you!

Comment: Try Ruppert, Wand and Carroll (2003). http://www.amazon.com/Semiparametric-Regression-Statistical-Probabilistic-Mathematics/dp/0521785162

Comment: To other readers of the post, there is an R package and the following intro by Wand for the topic: http://www.uow.edu.au/~mwand/SPmanu.pdf

Comment: Wand himself also pointed me to the package [mgcv](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mgcv/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of a monthly load model that clearly shows the role of temperature.

http://revgr.com/2012/11/06/all-forecasts-are-wrong-but-some-generate-fewer-complaints/

Comment: Thanks - this is a nice post! Maybe not directly applicable to my intraday setting, but very illustrative.

Comment: @Richard - I don't know the details of your particular problem, but is it possible that using monthly data to estimate the temperature coefficients is a worthwhile first step?   Using those coefficients, can't temperature be "removed" from the intraday data so that what's left is the hourly "population/activity" term?

Comment: At the moment I don't have enough data history (it is data per customer) that's my problem. But thanks again your input is definitely useful.